# Can't use "not", "or", or "plus" as identifier?

Tags: c++, c++11, keyword, reserved-words

I tried to compile this:

```
enum class conditional_operator { plus, or, not };
```

But apparently GCC (4.6) thinks these are special, while I can't find a standard that says they are (neither C++0x n3290 or C99 n2794). I'm compiling with `g++ -pedantic -std=c++0x`. Is this a compiler convenience? How do I turn it off? Shouldn't `-std=c++0x` turn this "feature" off?

PS: Hmmm, apparently, MarkDown code formatting thinks so too...

Comment: Amusing how the code correctly color both `or` and `not` as reserved but set `plus` apart :) Personally, I would favor dumping the use of `||` and `&&` in favor of `or` and `and` (resp), much less confusion with bitwise operators.

Comment: my colleague has code in the works that uses `or` and `and` as member function names. I'm eagerly waiting for him to try out and cry loud.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at 2.5.  They are alternative tokens for `||` and `!`.

There is a bunch of other alternative tokens BTW.

Edit: The rationale for their inclusion is the same as the one of trigraphs: allow the use of non ASCII character sets.  The committee has tried to get rid of them (at least of trigraphs, I don't remember for alternative tokens), and has met opposition of people (mostly IBM mainframe users) which are using them.

Edit for completeness: as other have make the remarks, plus isn't in that class and should not be a problem unless you are `using namespace std`.

Comment: +1 for the Standard section, although @Jon's link already let me find it.

Answer (score 7):

These are actually [defined as alternative tokens](http://cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_alternative) (and reserved) oddly enough, as alternative representations for operators. I believe this was originally to aid people who were using keyboards which made the relevant symbols hard to produce, although this seems a pretty poor reason to add extra keywords to the language :(

There *may* be a GCC compiler option to disable them, but I'm not sure.

(As mentioned in comments, `plus` should be okay unless you're using the `std` namespace.)

Comment: Technically, they aren't keywords (the effect in the preprocessor is different).

Comment: @AProgrammer: Ah, I was just going by the page I linked to. Is your term ("alternative tokens") the best one to use? I assume they're still reserved in the same way that keywords are?

Comment: It is the title of section 2.5 and of table 2.

Answer (score 5):

`or` and `not` are alternative representations of `||` and `!` respectively. You can't turn them off and you can't use these tokens for anything else, they are part of the language (current C++, not even just C++0x). ( See ISO/IEC 14882:2003 2.5 [lex.digraph] and 2.11 [lex.key] / 2. )

You should be safe with `plus` unless you use `using namespace std;` or `using std::plus;`.

Comment: +1 for being the first to point out that `plus` should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard lists keywords in 2.11.  There's also a list of alternative representations separate from the keyword list that is reserved and can't be used otherwise, but aren't keywords.  `and` and `or` are on that list.  Section 17.4.3 describes restrictions on programs that use libraries, and 17.4.3.1.3 describes that names declared with external linkage in a header are reserved both in `std::` and the global namespace.

In other words, you don't have to go to C++0x to have those problems.  `and` and `or` are already reserved, and header `<functional>` contains `plus` as a templated struct type, and `plus` is therefore off-limits if `<functional>` is directly or indirectly `#include`d.

I'm not sure dumping that much stuff into the global namespace was really wise, but that's what the standard says.

Comment: Wow, the alternative representation table was on the next page `:s`. I also didn't know about the `plus` issue. Guess I'll have to resort to `plus_op`, `or_op`, and `not_op`...

Comment: I think that saying that `plus` is off limits is a bit strong. It's "safely" embedded in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @Charles Bailey:  17.4.3.1.3/1:  "Each name declared as an object with external linkage in a header is reserved to the implementation to designate that library with external linkage, both in namespace std and in the global namespace."  It seems odd to me, too.

Comment: But a class template isn't an object. I think you've misinterpreted this section. It's referring to things like `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`, `cin`, `errno`, not classes and tempates. I can't think of any others off hand but I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

It is an year 1995 amendment to the C90 standard. Probably a compiler may choose on how to behave on this. GCC probably includes the header as part of the standard library. With microsoft it doesn't and you have to include the [iso646.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw6140c5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h) to wikipedia regarding this.

Comment: This question is about C++, though.

Comment: @Charles: but this is actually the reason it is in the C++ standard, because it was originally in C (if I understand correctly, I've been wrong before...)

Comment: there is a section regarding C++ on the wiki.