# Need a map from enum (class) to std::binary_function

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, functional-programming

I have this enum (class)

```
enum class conditional_operator
{
    plus_op,
    or_op,
    not_op
}
```

And I'd like a `std::map` that represents these mappings:

```
std::map<conditional_operator, std::binary_function<bool,bool,bool>> conditional_map = 
        { { conditional_operator::plus_op, std::logical_and<bool> },
          { conditional_operator::or_op,   std::logical_or<bool>},
          { conditional_operator::not_op,  std::binary_negate<bool>} // this seems fishy too, binary_negate is not really what I want :(
```

Apart from the fact that this doesn't compile:

> error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
>
> error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
>
> error: expected primary-expression before '}' token

for each of the three lines, how should I do this? I think a logical_not with a second dummy argument would work, once I get this to compile of course...

EDIT: Could I use lambda's for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really want `std::function<bool(bool, bool)>`, not `std::binary_function<bool, bool, bool>`. That only exists for typedefs and stuff in C++03. Secondly, I'd just use a lambda- they're short enough and much clearer. The `std::logical_and` and stuff only exists for C++03 function object creation, and I'd use a lambda over them any day.

```
std::map<conditional_operator, std::function<bool(bool,bool)>> conditional_map = 
{ 
    { conditional_operator::plus_op, [](bool a, bool b) { return a && b; } },
    { conditional_operator::or_op,   [](bool a, bool b) { return a || b; } },
    { conditional_operator::not_op,  [](bool a, bool b) { return !a; } }
};
```

Wait- what exact operator are you referring to with not? Because that's unary, as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I want it unified in this map, so I don't have to go looking for something else, perhaps `[](bool a, bool) { return !a; }`? And wouldn't the existing templates like `logical_and` and `logical_or` be "better", because for one, I didn't write them (ie use the library when it provides what you need). Of course the `not_op` would become a problem. (Also note that [your code is ill-formed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253351/cant-use-not-or-or-plus-as-identifier))

Comment: @rubenvb: So is yours- I copied it from your example. I would favour a lambda over that kind of function object because the code is inline and easier to change if you ask me.

Comment: Should it be `std::function<bool(bool,bool)>` instead of `std::function<bool,bool,bool>`?

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, it should be. Teach me to copy and paste code without fully reading it :P

Answer (score 2):

@DeadMG’s answer is spot-on but if you insist on using the predefined function objects, you need to *instantiate* them. At the moment you’re just passing their type names.

That is, you need to write `std::logical_***<bool>()` instead of just `std::logical_***<bool>`.

Comment: oh, whaddayaknow, another pro for the lambda's. I'm  beginning to appreciate lambda's more and more :)

Comment: @rubenvb: the syntax you use would work if they were defined as template functions instead of template classes.